# Jquery - JSON Parse with hash character in key

Tags: jquery, json, hash

I'm make a script for parse json with jquery but same key in the json have a hash character:

```
"image":[{"#text":"aaaaaaaaaaaaa","size":"bbbbbbbbbbbb"}
```

so the javascript generate errors

```
$.each(item, function(y,img){
     alert(y+" ----- "+img.#text+"  "+img.size);
});
```

how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

Try accessing the object member using `[]` notation:

```
alert(y + " ----- " + img['#text'] + "  " + img.size);
```